# Salesforce Community & Flows

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, visual-flows, flowscreen

I recently joined a Salesforce community development project. The site is completely developed using Salesforce flows. If I go to Community builder, there is just 1 flow component. Flows are quite massive, example shown below. Can you please comment on this design approach, right or wrong and advantages/disadvantages. I see this as single point of failure, once the flow goes wrong the site is also down.

[image]

Comment: From a maintenance standpoint, this looks like a nightmare. I would split this up into subflows so that way different subflows can be updated and tested in isolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree and tend to feel that every SObject in the domain layer should either be managed by Apex or a Flow but never both.

Your example looks like somewhat I see a lot with Flows. A declarative god class and I assume there are no tests for it either.  I am of the opinion that Salesforce is doing more harm than good with the current "avoid code at all costs" mantra they seem to be pushing.  No human being will be able to look at that flow and reason effectively about it.